# How are fees denominated on Aurora network?

Tags: ethereum, nearprotocol, aurora-evm, aurora-near

Are fees denominated in NEAR or is there an ETH token equivalent for fees that RPC operators would then collect in return for sending the wrapped transaction (thereby spending NEAR)?

Comment: We have separate Stack Exchange sites for blockchain questions. They're only on topic here if you have a specific, narrow, practical problem you encountered writing related code.

Comment: See in particular [Ethereum.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the RPC (relayer) is that Aurora is completely abstracting from NEAR, and creating a fully compatible Ethereum ecosystem. The transaction that is being executed on chain will be consuming NEAR to pay for the gas, but this will be abstracted away by the RPC, which will charge the equivalent in ETH and pay the NEAR tokens itself.
So basically when a user signs a transaction, it includes a fee that is sent to the RPC (the Relayer submitting the transaction to NEAR). Gas fee is paid with NEAR token by the relayer, but they get some ETH back. Currently the fee being charged by Aurora RPC is 0, so basically transactions can be sent for free right now, this will change in the future for Aurora RPC, but others can run the same RPC and use different policies.